# How to get iTunes to reconnect after buffering?

Tags: itunes, windows

If I am streaming internet radio and iTunes looses the signal it will try to reconnect and then just gives up and moves to the next track in the playlist of internet songs.

Is there a way to change iTunes config so that it continues trying to reconnect rather than just giving up? Like a time-out perhaps?

I am running iTunes 11.3.1.2 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the time-out within iTunes easily. But there is another solution to your problem.

[image: iTunes internet songs playlist]

## Create a playlist of an internet stream

- Go to the iTunes Internet tab.
- Select your radiostation
- Get Info (File -> Get Info, or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>)
- In the info screen, select the Summary section
- Right click the URL next to **Where:**, 'Copy URL'
- Now open this stream (File -> Open Stream, or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, paste, OK)

This should create a new playlist "Internet Songs". As it only contains 1 'Internet Song', this should keep your from skipping to the next stream.

[image: iTunes info screen]

Comment: This was the first radio station I could find

Comment: Seems kinda hacky but might work.. There is no config setting that would just retry the existing stream?

Comment: Not that I know of. You might be able to 'hack' some plist settings. Btw, I thought this a pretty clean way to handle the problem.

Comment: This is a pretty elegant solution. Practical, easy to understand, easy to implement.

Comment: @snowgage, does it work?

Comment: My question asks if there is a way to do this my changing an iTunes config parameter not be creating a playlist.

Comment: And that is not possible, therefor this solution.